# codeigniter session destroy two different application

Tags: codeigniter

For example i am using two admin panel.Once I destroy all session value through one admin panel, another one admin session value also will destroyed . I am using unset and `session_destroy` for both admin panel. Is this any way to prevent one another

Answer (score 0):

if you are using both panel in the same broswer. Then it will be destroyed. Using different browser might help. That's how session are made to work.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Instead of session_destroy used unset for particular variable.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** Do not use [**`session_destroy()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php), it destroys all data registered to a session. 
So better to use [**`unset()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php), it unset a given variable passed to the function. Also avoid the same session variable names.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments. Its working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

use tow different sessions for admin panels and unset the particular admin session data instead of destroying all session data.